# Does Mordenkainen's Private Sanctum prevent Devil's Sight from working?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock

I could compare it to [this question about whether the Devil's Sight invocation allows one to see into Hunger of Hadar](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59960/does-devils-sight-enable-one-to-see-into-hunger-of-hadar), but that question has an easy answer, due to the 'blinded' condition it affects the person inside with. However, the spell [Mordenkainen's Private Sanctum](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Private%20Sanctum) does not give the 'blinded' effect- it merely states that, in one of its properties:

> The barrier of the warded area appears dark and foggy, preventing vision (including darkvision) through it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## It does prevent Devil's Sight

As seen in the PHB list of spells:

> **[Devil's Sight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#EldritchInvocations)**. You can see normally in darkness, both magical and nonmagical, to a distance of 120 feet.
>
> **[Private Sanctum](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/private-sanctum)**. The barrier of the warded area appears dark and foggy, preventing vision (including darkvision) through it.

And having the creative intention behind Devil's Sight explained by Jeremy Crawford:

> **[Jeremy Crawford on Twitter](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/704828756616044544)**. Devil's Sight is meant to pierce the dark created by a spell like darkness, not the void of hunger of Hadar.

Private sanctum seems to not create magical darkness, but make the area on the inside look dark and **foggy** when looking from the outside. So even if Devil's Sight would pierce the darkness(Which I don't believe it does in this case) it still cannot pierce the fog.

Thank you Slagmoth for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: Please cite your sources for quotations. Also note that while JC's tweet is interesting and can be some additional support, it is not official in any way.

Comment: If it is foggy how can Devil's Sight penetrate the obscurity? I think their wording is poor but only the darkness part of that ward is ignored by Devil's Sight.

Comment: Now that meantion it, it does say foggy. That word really does complicate the situation. I'll rethink the answer