# What happens if the Daylight spell overlaps with the Hunger of Hadar spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The [*hunger of Hadar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hunger-of-hadar) spell states:

> You open a gateway to the dark between the stars, a region infested with unknown horrors. A 20-foot-radius **sphere of blackness** and bitter cold appears, centered on a point with range and lasting for the duration. This void is filled with a cacophony of soft whispers and slurping noises that can be heard up to 30 feet away. **No light, magical or otherwise, can illuminate the area**, and creatures fully within the area are blinded.
>
> The void creates a warp in the fabric of space, and the area is difficult terrain. Any creature that starts its turn in the area takes 2d6 cold damage. Any creature that ends its turn in the area must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw or take 2d6 acid damage as milky, otherwordly tentacles rub against it.

And the [*daylight*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/daylight) spell states:

> A 60-foot-radius sphere of light spreads out from a point you choose within range. The sphere is bright light and sheds dim light for an additional 60 feet.
>
> If you chose a point on an object you are holding or one that isn't being worn or carried, the light shines from the object and moves with it. Completely covering the affected object with an opaque object, such as a bowl or a helm, blocks the light.
>
> **If any of this spell's area overlaps with an area of darkness created by a spell of 3rd level or lower, the spell that created the darkness is dispelled.**

**Which of these spells is more specific and wins out over the other? What happens if their areas overlap?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hunger of Hadar doesn't create darkness (in the sense of game mechanics), magical or otherwise; it just creates a black void of space, so the Daylight spell wouldn't affect it.

Comment: It doesn't even create the void, it just opens a portal to it.

Comment: Yep. This is also why [Devil's Sight doesn't see through *hunger of Hadar*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/76450/33569), at least per designer intent.