# Can Truesight see through an area that is heavily obscured?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, vision-and-light, special-senses

[Truesight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Truesight) states:

> A monster with truesight can ... see in **normal and magical darkness**, **see invisible creatures and objects**, [and] automatically detect **visual illusions** ...

[Heavily obscured](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/adventuring#VisionandLight) is created by a variety of effects as noted in its description:

> A heavily obscured area—such as darkness, opaque fog, or dense foliage—blocks vision entirely.

Now, we know that [Truesight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Truesight) can see through darkness of any kind, and so if the heavily obscured area was created by darkness, Truesight would be unaffected.

However, there are a variety of game effects that create a non-darkness-related area that is heavily obscured such as the spells below:

[Fog Cloud](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fog-cloud)

> The sphere spreads around corners, and its area is **heavily obscured**.

[Cloudkill](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/cloudkill)

> Its area is **heavily obscured**.

For example, if a [mezzoloth](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17124-mezzoloth) were to cast [Cloudkill](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/cloudkill) on itself to hide from a player using the [Shield of the Hidden Lord](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/843176-shield-of-the-hidden-lord)'s [Truesight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Truesight) ability, could the Shield see it?

**Can Truesight see through an area that is heavily obscured?**

Comment: Related: [Does Shadow of Moil heavily obscure you against an opponent with Truesight?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/167411/does-shadow-of-moil-heavily-obscure-you-against-an-opponent-with-truesight)

Comment: @Kirt LOL, that question is the exact reason that I asked *this* question! I threw in the mezzoloth just as an example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Truesight can see through exactly the things it says it can.

There’s an oft quoted phrase that applies to your question, “spells do what they say they do”. In this case, we’re talking about a special sense, which the rules define for us. Truesight allows you see:

- in normal and magical darkness
- invisible creatures and objects
- visual illusions
- the original form of a shapechanger or a creature that is transformed by magic.
- into the Ethereal Plane

If the thing obscuring your vision isn’t on this list, truesight doesn’t help.