# Does the Devil’s Sight eldritch invocation counter the Blinded condition?

Tags: dnd-5e, vision-and-light, eldritch-invocations, blind, special-senses

The [Devil’s Sight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#DevilsSight) eldritch invocation for warlocks says:

> **You can see normally** in darkness, both magical and nonmagical, to a distance of 120 feet.

Does this mean that if you are blinded, casting *darkness* on yourself (or otherwise removing all light) will let you ignore the blinded condition?

Comment: Related: "[Does Devil's Sight enable one to see into Hunger of Hadar?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59960)"

Comment: Also related: "[Can you blind a Demilich/creature that has Truesight?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72157)"

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for a green check?

Answer (score 11):

#### No, you must be able to see to be able to see normally in darkness.

The blinded condition says:

> *A blinded creature can't see* and automatically fails any ability check that requires sight.

If devil's sight granted conditional immunity to the blindness condition, it would say so. As written, Devil's Sight improves sight; if you are blind, there is no sight to improve.

In answering [a similar question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/72157) about *truesight*, nitsua60 writes:

> The only thing *Truesight* does in this case is magnify the ability that was lost to *blindness*:
>
> *Truesight* **enhances** one's ability to see: through magical darkness, invisibility, illusions, shapechanges, and into the Ethereal (PHB p.185).
>
> But the *blindness* condition now says **"you can't see.** The sight through illusions, darkness, &c. which you so enjoyed just a moment ago, you don't **have** anymore (PHB p.290, paraphrased)."

In similar fashion, Devil's Sight only improves that sense which is lost entirely to blindness.